# After enabling fileinfo extension and restarting Apache it still does not load

Tags: php, apache, xampp, php-extension, fileinfo

I want to use fileinfo extension in PHP (5.5). (On localhost(Windows), using XAMPP)

So I went to php.ini and commented out `extension=php_fileinfo.dll`, then I HAVE restarted the apache, even tried to restart the whole PC.

But when I try to use it I still get function/class does not exists ... (procedural/objective)

When I looked to the php_info() page, there is "fileinfo" listed **but** only among the "Module Authors" table - and that is , I presume, not enaugh - is it?

Does anybody know how to solve this?

**PS:** I checked the php.ini for magic path and there is 
`mime_magic.magicfile = "\xampp\php\extras\magic.mime"`

However there is no such file in the whole xampp folder structure... - could that be a reason why is not loading? Where would I download this file?

Many thanks !

**PS2:** Solution for others with the same problem who want only images to upload:

```
  $image_size_info = @getimagesize($filename); //surpress errors(@) if not image
  if( empty($image_size_info) ) $mime_type = "";
    else $mime_type = @image_type_to_mime_type( $image_size_info[2] );

  //safety for all cases:
  if( empty($mime_type) ) $mime_type = "";

  if(  strpos($mime_type, "image/") === false  ){
    //not an Image !
  } else {
    //proceed file upload
  }
```